# Raspberry pi 4 Not Booting Solid Red One Green Flash

Tags: pi-4

Hello I have a raspberry pi 4 and after it was lying for some time in a drawer I decided to use it for something and it doesn't work. I'm sure it used to work before and even though it was just lying in a drawer it just stopped working. When I plug it in the red led is solid and green led blinks for maybe half a second. I tried multiple SD cards (known good ones) and multiple power supplies (also connected it to laboratory power supply to make just to make sure but the same problem, also it's constantly drawin like 300ma).

There is no display over HDMI with or without the SD card. Also pi is acting the same no matter if the card is plugged in or not (same as described before red light one short green blink when connecting power). All voltages seem to be present but there is no power on the USB ports even though there is 5v at GPIO, the SD card and the ethernet seem to be getting powered as well. SD card slot is in good shape as well.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAJJp.jpg images of the pi

Is there an option to fix it? I'm fine with soldering so if it's some broken component I can get it and replace it.
Thanks for help

Comment: It doesnt get very hot

Comment: In that case you need to go to raspberrypi.org/forums and find the boot sticky.  work through the suggestions.

Comment: I already read everything on that page and none of the solutions are about my problem.

Comment: This may sound like a redundant question but, you say you tried multiple SD cards, you haven't mentioned what operating system you put on them and how you put it on them

Comment: Raspbian, NOOBS, ubuntu a lot of diffrent stuff I most likely have the same problem as here https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=253776&hilit=raspberry+pi+4+can%27t+update+eeprom but I still have no idea how to fix it